# Different deprecation warning behaviour for Kotlin and Java projects, when executing androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.startActivityForResult

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-appcompat

I have 2 projects. 1 is Java, another 1 is Kotlin.

Both are using

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
```

However, I notice they are calling different function, when I try to call `androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.startActivityForResult(Intent, int)`

---

### In Java

When calling `androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.startActivityForResult(Intent, int)`, it will step into

```
androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(@NonNull Intent intent, int requestCode)
```

which is currently deprecated.

[image]

---

### In Kotlin

When calling `androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.startActivityForResult(Intent, int)`, it will step into

```
androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(@SuppressLint("UnknownNullness") Intent intent, int requestCode)
```

which is currently **NOT** deprecated.

[image]

---

The reason I start to look into this, is because I do not get expected deprecated warning when using `startActivityForResult` in Kotlin project.

When I investigate further, I notice Kotlin has different code path from Java, when calling `androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.startActivityForResult(Intent, int)`

Is this the correct behavior? May I know why it is so?